# SignalR package upgrade giving exception in Asp.net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working on an angular project using asp.net core 2.1.

I want to implement signalR in my application for that I have upgraded some packages as given below :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core -Version 1.0.2 
npm i @aspnet/signalr
```

and some more packages which system asked me to do(bcz of version issues)

In stratup class there is a function which was working properly but now its giving below error.

Funcftion `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` throw an error while control comes on `services.AddSignalR();`.

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.IInvocationBinder' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common, Version=1.0.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

**Edit :**  After installing Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR latest and related dependencies, I am getting below error in program.cs

```
      public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); //exception here
            }
   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'System.Threading.PipeScheduler' from assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.'

Comment: Try with Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR -Version 1.0.2. It seems that you didn't update all signalr

Comment: I have installed latest Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR now getting error in program.cs pls check updated question..

Comment: Installing packages is a biggg headache, need to install lots of dependencies .. and still not fixed ..

Comment: System.IO.Pipelines was just introduced in the latest .NET Core. Likely, you need to update the .NET Core SDK on your machine.

Comment: I am already using sdk 2.1.. and before updating packages it was working..Do I need to install latest sdk @ChrisPratt???

Comment: There's different patch versions of 2.1. Make sure you have the latest.

Comment: I have installed the latest one but now failed to build the project, error "The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.0-rc1, but with current settings, version 2.1.0 would be used instead.  To resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore and for subsequent operations such as build or publish.  Typically this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or publish but not during restore."

Comment: I have installed 2.1.302 previous version was 2.1.300..